Getting error while trying to disable Azure DevOps pipeline using Powershell
I am trying to disable a build pipeline on Azure DevOps using Powershell but getting an error
Script:
$project = "<Project-Name>"

$organization = "<Org-Name>"
$pat = "<PAT>"

$base64AuthInfo = [Convert]::ToBase64String([Text.Encoding]::ASCII.GetBytes(":$($pat)"))


$headers = @{
    Authorization = "Basic $base64AuthInfo"
    "Content-Type" = "application/json"
}


$pipelineDetailsUrl = "https://dev.azure.com/$organization/$project/_apis/pipelines/<ID>?api-version=6.0"
$pipelineDetails = Invoke-RestMethod -Uri $pipelineDetailsUrl -Method Get -Headers $headers
$pipelineDetails.configuration.designerJson.queueStatus = "disabled"
$body = $pipelineDetails | ConvertTo-Json -Depth 10
Invoke-RestMethod -Uri $pipelineDetailsUrl -Method Put -Headers $headers -Body $body -ContentType "application/json"

However I am getting below error

Invoke-RestMethod : {"count":1,"value":{"Message":"The requested resource does not support http method 'PUT'."}}


Good day to you. It seemed that the answer by Rui was using the same definition-update API endpoint as that in your answer. Shall we consider the issue in this post is resolved? Thanks for your time to share the update. Cheers.

The right endpoints to use are the following:

Definitions - Get
Definitions - Update

Example
$PROJECT="my-project"
$ORGANIZATION="https://dev.azure.com/my-organization"
$TOKEN="xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx"

$BUILD_DEFINITION_ID="123"

# Base64-encode the Personal Access Token (PAT)
$base64AuthInfo = [Convert]::ToBase64String([Text.Encoding]::ASCII.GetBytes(":$($TOKEN)"))

# Same URL for getting the build definition and updating it
$apiUrl = "{0}/{1}/_apis/build/definitions/{2}?api-version=7.2-preview.7" -f $ORGANIZATION, $PROJECT, $BUILD_DEFINITION_ID

Write-Host "Endpoint: $apiUrl"

$headers = @{
  Authorization=("Basic {0}" -f $base64AuthInfo)
  Accept="application/json"
  "Content-Type"="application/json"
}

$definition = Invoke-RestMethod -Uri $apiUrl -Headers $headers -Method GET
# $definition.queueStatus = "enabled"
# $definition.queueStatus = "paused"
$definition.queueStatus = "disabled"

$body = $definition | ConvertTo-Json

$response = Invoke-RestMethod -Uri $apiUrl -Headers $headers -Method PUT -Body $body

Write-Host $response


Update
Found the problem, it was the endpoint I was trying to hit, instead of
"https://dev.azure.com/$organization/$project/_apis/pipelines/<ID>?api-version=6.0"

use
"https://dev.azure.com/$organization/$project/_apis/build/definitions/<ID>?api-version=6.0"


Is the endpoint the only thing you've changed in the script you posted above?

Yes changing the endpoint resolved my issue, the attribute was the same "queuestatus"

The error message says that the Azure DevOps REST API does not support the HTTP PUT method for the endpoint you're using. To disable a build pipeline, you should use the correct endpoint and method supported by the Azure DevOps API. Like this:
$project = "<Project-Name>"
$organization = "<Org-Name>"
$pipelineId = "<Pipeline-ID>"  # Update with the actual pipeline ID
$pat = "<PAT>"

$base64AuthInfo = [Convert]::ToBase64String([Text.Encoding]::ASCII.GetBytes(":$($pat)"))

$headers = @{
    Authorization = "Basic $base64AuthInfo"
    "Content-Type" = "application/json"
}

# Get the pipeline details
$pipelineDetailsUrl = "https://dev.azure.com/$organization/$project/_apis/pipelines/$pipelineId?api-version=6.0-preview.1"
$pipelineDetails = Invoke-RestMethod -Uri $pipelineDetailsUrl -Method Get -Headers $headers

# Set the pipeline to disabled
$pipelineDetails.configuration = $pipelineDetails.configuration | ForEach-Object {
    $_.enabled = $false
    $_
}

$body = $pipelineDetails | ConvertTo-Json -Depth 10

# Update the pipeline with the new configuration
$updatePipelineUrl = "https://dev.azure.com/$organization/$project/_apis/pipelines/$pipelineId?api-version=6.0-preview.1"
Invoke-RestMethod -Uri $updatePipelineUrl -Method Put -Headers $headers -Body $body -ContentType "application/json"

The script first retrieves the pipeline details using a GET request.
It then modifies the enabled property of the pipeline configuration to false.
Finally, it sends a PUT request with the updated pipeline details to disable the pipeline.

Hi Stina, above did not work giving error
Exception setting "enabled": "The property 'enabled' cannot be found on this object. Verify that the property exists and can be set."
